# Java game, Rectangle for the background is moving

Tags: java, awt, java-2d, coordinate-systems, rectangles

I hope that the title has not made this post more confusing than it already is. The problem I am having may be better explained if I tell you exactly what I have done so far:

**The Game**

I have made a very simple 2D game, the basics are, a player moves around a 2D map with keyboard input (up, down, left. right arrows) this game is kind of like a pokemon view where the view is from the top, his speed is set simply by using the following code for each keyboard input:

```
 if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){
    bucky = movingDown;
    buckyPositionY -= 2;
    if(buckyPositionY<-550){//this is used to stop player from leaving the map
        buckyPositionY += 2;}}
```

The same is done for the other 3 keyboard inputs.

**The Problem**

I have made the game where the player can move around but the problem is I have objects on the map and at the moment my player just walks through them, so I need to set up collisions, I know how to set up collisions using the rectangle method but the problem is actually making the rectangles. I know it is a simple task but on this game whenever I place my Rectangle down it moves when I move my player, I tested for this by drawing the rectangle with the following code:

```
g.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
```

Thats the coordinates for an obstacle on my map, when I draw the rectangle it appears on the top left cornor of my screen and when I move my player it stays there (it keeps moving to stay in the top left cornor), now this is a big problem for me because if my rectangles are moving how is my collision supposed to work. I think the reason that this is happening is because my map is very big meaning that rather than showing the full thing I just centered my player on the center of my screen and when he moves the screen also moves with him to show the rest of the map.

**The Code**

Here is the code in my game class, it has methods such as render, init and update in it but I think the only code required to fix this problem is the render method and the variables so here they are (if the full code is required please tell me)

*The Variables*

```
 Animation bucky, movingUp, movingDown, movingLeft, movingRight
Image worldMap;
boolean quit = false;
int[] duration = {200, 200};
int buckyPositionX = 0;
int buckyPositionY = 0;
int shiftX = buckyPositionX + 320;
int shiftY = buckyPositionY + 160;
```

*The render Method*

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
worldMap.draw(buckyPositionX, buckyPositionY);//position 0,0
bucky.draw(shiftX, shiftY);//makes him appear at center of map

if(quit==true){
    g.drawString("Resume(R)", 250, 100);
    g.drawString("Main(M)", 250, 150);
    g.drawString("Quit Game(Q)", 250, 200);      
    if(quit==false){
        g.clear();
    }}}
```

I am sorry about this thread being so long bit if you could please take the time to help me and answer my question I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is occurring because the drawing coordinates are defined with respect to the screen, not the game map, i.e. a coordinate of (0,0) means the top-left of the screen, not top left of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said the rectangles(obstacles) are moving because the drawing coordinates are defined with respect to the screen, not the game map. That is when the character moves and you repaint the game map the rectangle is still drawn at (0,0) i.e. top-left of the screen.

Here are some suggestions.

- Use a seperate offscreen `Image` for the game map. The image size will be of
  the same size as of the game map.
- Rectangles(obstacles) & other stuff excluding the character should be drawn on this image by getting a graphic context of this image using `getGraphics`
- Finally when the character moves you paint a part of the image on screen using `drawImage(Image img, int dstx1, int dsty1, int dstx2, int dsty2, int srcx1, int srcy1, int srcx2, int srcy2, ImageObserver observer)` method. The explanation of this method is avaliable [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html). You have to calculate which part of the image to paint from the position of the character

A thing to keep in mind is the character should only be drawn on screen, not on the game map `Image`. The character should be drawn on screen after drawing the game map image.

Comment: Some useful terms to look at when researching this are: world co-ordinates versus screen/render co-ordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Java's 2-dimensional drawing methods draw relative to the the screen, not relative to a map.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect

If you want to draw relative to the map location, you will need to offset the position of the rectangle based on the position of the player on the map. Since your character animation is always at the center of the screen, you will need to offset any other animations based on where Bucky is on the map. So your rectangle drawing needs to look something like:

```
g.fillRect(0 + buckyPositionX, 0 + buckyPositionY, 100, 100);
```

A better solution would be to track a camera position over the map, and then draw everything relative to the camera, including your character. This gives you freedom to do in game cut scenes and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much, the code you have told me has fixed my problem and also helped me understand the code, THANK YOU!

Comment: Also, you might want to ask further questions for your game on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ so that you get better focused feedback.